# How to set the table cell margin to 0?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Horizontally, I'm trying to glue left and right cells by "-" without any white space between them. So I tired to create a middle cell between them with content "-", but it has margin among three cells, so I wondered how do I get rid of the white space (`padding` and `margin`) between the middle cell and other cells?

HTML

```
<table id="test">
    <tr id="userr1">
        <th>Left</th>
        <th class="mid">-</th>
        <th>Right</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>cell</td>
        <td class="mid">-</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>cell</td>
        <td class="mid">-</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
#test, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
}
.mid {
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/84/

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: effective and simple. this is the one i like most

Answer (score 0):

You're missing padding: 0px; for the

## test, th, td {}

```
#test, th, td {
border:1px solid black;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
  
}
```